# WP7 Better Performance Concepts

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I've been trying to research how to increase performance of my Windows Phone 7 app and make it production ready.  Currently, there are some fast parts, some slow parts and some that are acceptable.

The main problem I have is navigating to the "main page", which contains a list of about 100 items.  When navigated to I am assuming this list has to regenerate itself, thus taking a few seconds to fully navigate back to the page.

I am going to be "releasing" it with this slower navigation since I've put a lot of work into it (nearly 2 months of coding), but I am also working on a "Recode" for the Mango release.

I'd like to know what people are doing to make thier applications superfast, or any concepts or pattern implementations out there.

One idea I had is to only have 1 page and load all the needed elements dynamically into that page (however I am not sure where to start with that, if you know please add).

Overall, I'd like to get some ideas (and links/samples) so when I redesign this it's a super fast app.

Thanks Alot!

Comment: There should be plenty of controls around to make a virtualized list. But have you measured it to see if that is where your actual problem is?

Comment: Are you targetting 7.0 or 7.1 ("Mango")? If 7.0, then the `silverlight-4.0` tag is incorrect as 7.0 uses SL3

Comment: Conversation says re-write for Mango (i.e. SL4) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/10/12/procrastination-ftw-lazylistbox-should-improve-your-scrolling-performance-and-responsiveness.aspx

but there is on gotcha regarding to Mango - just keep that in mind.

Comment: the gotcha is that you need to do a bit of a tweak because it won't work on Mango... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/04/13/pull-down-to-refresh-a-wp7-listbox-or-scrollviewer.aspx - check the "update" stuff at the bottom of the page

Comment: This looks like a promising solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Performance team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/)